# Can you display a form radio or list component as a row instead of a column?

Tags: sitecore-forms

0-10 customer satisfaction survey that I would like to display as a row not a column.  Using a Radio or list component within a form, though open to other ways. Limited CSS options avaailable.

Comment: I happen to disagree with the Close vote, it's quite clear to me what you want to achieve. But I don't have enough rep here to do anything about it. You could opt for a number-field and set the min-value to 0 and the max-value to 10? If you really want to use the radio-button then this is more a CSS question, in which case share with us what you've tried in terms of CSS to get the `<input type="radio">` tags in one row (something with `display: inline-block;` probably?)

Comment: @asontu the close vote was to focus the question and get it clarified. You, yourself, request clarification.